# Referncing a cell, based on a cell's value in Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I understand how referencing a cell works, example being

```
=Sheet1.A1
```

However, if I'm in Sheet2 and cell B1 contains `Sheet1`, and cell C1 contains `A1`.

Is there any way to write the reference such that it uses the values from B1 and C1 to determine where the reference should point to?

Comment: You would use `Sheet1!A1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ! after the sheet name for the basic formula, like this

`=Sheet1!A1`

You can use INDIRECT to convert a text reference to an actual one, so for your example try

`=INDIRECT(B1&"!"&C1)`

Sheet names with spaces (and some other characteristics) also need single quotes around them e.g.`'Sheet one'!A1` so to cover all possible sheet names you can change to this version

`=INDIRECT("'"&B1&"'!"&C1)`